# ¿Es complatible AdminLTE 3 con livewire?

Tags: livewire, adminlte

amig@s programadores.

Les comento, tengo una aplicación, un proyecto en laravel 8. Le instale Jeststream que me permite manejar el tema de la autenticación.
Luego instale livewire, para incluir reactividad... y desarrolle un CRUD de la tabla users. y funciono perfecto.

Luego instale el framework AdminLTE 3.... por la parte grafica y los elementos que ofrece. Se que esta diseñado sobre la base de Bootstrap 3.
Pero al intentar unir AdminLTE con livewire, no se activa la reactividad....
Alguna sugerencia o conocimiento previo. Si se pueden integrar en un solo proyecto todas estas tecnologías????
El punto es que cuando uso el componente y el menu de jestream, (el que se instala por defecto me funciona bien.
Aqui una imagen
[image: uso de livewire con jestream]

Pero si le agrego el  @extends('adminlte::page') del AdminLTE no hay reactividad

[image: adminLte con livewire]

No abre el modal para crear un registro nuevo, no abre el modal para edicion y no elimina.
Si por obligo a que se abra el modal colocando en true la variable public $isOpen = true;
obtengo este resultado:

[image: modal para agregar un nuevo registro]

Cualquier sugerencia u observacion se la agradezco.

```html
@extends('adminlte::page')

@section('title', 'Dashboard')

@section('content_header')
    <h1>Home compania</h1>
@stop
@livewireStyles
@section('content')
    
    @livewire('compania')
@stop

@section('css')
    
     <!-- Styles -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
@stop

@section('js')
    <script> console.log('Home_compania!'); </script>
@stop
```

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Company;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class Compania extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public $title;
    public $company_id;
    public $isOpen = true;
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.compania', [
            'companies' => Company::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(5)
        ]);
      
    }
    public function create()
    {
        $this->resetInputFields();
        $this->openModal();
    }

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public function openModal()
    {
        $this->isOpen = true;
        // Clean errors if were visible before
        $this->resetErrorBag();
        $this->resetValidation();
    }

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public function closeModal()
    {
        $this->isOpen = false;
    }

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    private function resetInputFields(){
        $this->title = '';
        $this->company_id = '';
    }

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */

    public function store()
    {
        $this->validate([
            'title' => 'required|unique:companies,title,'.$this->company_id,
        ]);
        $data = array(
            'title' => $this->title
        );
        $company = Company::updateOrCreate(['id' => $this->company_id],$data);
        session()->flash('message', $this->company_id ? 'Company updated successfully.' : 'Company created successfully.');
        $this->closeModal();
        $this->resetInputFields();
    }

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $company = Company::findOrFail($id);
        $this->company_id = $id;
        $this->title = $company->title;
        $this->openModal();
    }

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public function delete($id)
    {
        $this->company_id = $id;
        Company::find($id)->delete();
        session()->flash('message', 'Company deleted successfully.');
    }

}
```

```html
<div>
    {{-- Be like water. --}}
   
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        @if (session()->has('message'))
            <div id="alert" class="text-white px-6 py-4 border-0 rounded relative mb-4 bg-green-500">
                <span class="inline-block align-middle mr-8">
                    {{ session('message') }}
                </span>
                <button
                    class="absolute bg-transparent text-2xl font-semibold leading-none right-0 top-0 mt-4 mr-6 outline-none focus:outline-none"
                    onclick="document.getElementById('alert').remove();">
                    <span>×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        @endif
      
    </div>

    <button wire:click="create()"
    class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded mt-10">CREAR NUEVA COMPANIA</button>
    
@if (count($companies) > 0)
<div class="py-10">
    <div class="inline-block min-w-full shadow rounded-lg overflow-hidden">
        <table class="min-w-full leading-normal">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th
                        class="px-5 py-3 border-b-2 border-black bg-black text-left text-xs font-semibold text-white uppercase tracking-wider">
                        {{ __('Title') }}
                    </th>
                    <th
                        class="px-5 py-3 border-b-2 border-black bg-black text-left text-xs font-semibold text-white uppercase tracking-wider">
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach ($companies as $company)
                    <tr>
                        <td class="px-5 py-5 bg-white text-sm @if (!$loop->last) border-gray-200 border-b @endif">
                            {{ Str::limit($company->title, 25) }}
                        </td>
                        <td class="px-5 py-5 bg-white text-sm @if (!$loop->last) border-gray-200 border-b @endif text-right">
                            <div class="inline-block whitespace-no-wrap">
                                <button wire:click="edit({{ $company->id }})"
                                    class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">Edit</button>
                                <button wire:click="$emit('triggerDelete',{{ $company->id }})"
                                    class="bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">Delete</button>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>

        {{ $companies->links('pagination', ['is_livewire' => true]) }}
    </div>
</div>
@endif

@if ($isOpen)
<x-customised-modal>
    <x-slot name="content">
        <form>
            <div class="px-4 pt-5 pb-4 sm:p-6 sm:pb-4">
                <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6">
                    <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3 mb-6 md:mb-0">
                        <label for="titleInput"
                            class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">Title:</label>
                        <input type="text"
                            class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                            id="titleInput" placeholder="Enter Title" wire:model="title">
                        @error('title') <span class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="px-4 py-3 sm:px-6 sm:flex sm:flex-row-reverse">
                <span class="flex w-full sm:ml-3 sm:w-auto">
                    <button wire:click.prevent="store()" type="button"
                        class="inline-flex bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">Save</button>
                </span>
                <span class="mt-3 flex w-full sm:mt-0 sm:w-auto">
                    <button wire:click="closeModal()" type="button"
                        class="inline-flex bg-white hover:bg-gray-200 border border-gray-300 text-gray-500 font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">Cancel</button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </form>
    </x-slot>
</x-customised-modal>
@endif

@push('styles')
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10/dist/sweetalert2.min.css">
@endpush

@push('scripts')
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/promise-polyfill@8/dist/polyfill.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

        @this.on('triggerDelete', companyId => {
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Are You Sure?',
                text: 'Company record will be deleted!',
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: '#d33',
                cancelButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                confirmButtonText: 'Delete!'
            }).then((result) => {
                if (result.value) {
                    @this.call('delete', companyId)
                } else {
                    console.log("Canceled");
                }
            });
        });
    })
</script>
@endpush

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

En la configuración del adminlte config/adminlte.php, debes establecer en true el valor de "livewire"